# Credit Union changeover

Tags: banking, legal, credit-unions

I had an account with what used to be Montgomery County Teachers Federal Credit Union and now changed over to Educational Systems Federal Credit Union, which during the changeover for some reason my account suddenly closed and they said my secured loan against my own money was all paid up but my money was not available. What can I do?

Comment: Go to one of their offices and meet with the branch manager in person and don't leave until everything is cleared up.

Comment: when did the change take place?

Answer (score 3):

Go to one of their offices, say you need to speak to someone "on the platform" (banker terminology for folks above the teller level), tell them that you are confused about why and how this account was closed out, and ask them to explain exactly how it all balanced out and why they didn't talk with you about other ways to handle it.

If they can't explain it, with direct access to your account records and their policy documents, it's unlikely we'll be able to do so without all those private details.

If you understand their explanation but still aren't satisfied by it -- if you really think they've violated the terms of your accounts -- then you're going to need to find expert local advice. Which is likely to involve paying for that advice. Unless you can get a newspaper's ombudsman desk interested in it as a story.